# kafka stream processor api Global state store multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to create a kafka stream using processor api as i have custom process. I faced an issue when my processor was listning to multiple topics with different number of partitions. I realized i need to create a global state store. 
I need to know how to be able to add a processor and also add a global state store while that listens to multiple topics?

Any code examples or links will help.
Thank You!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A global state store can only read from a single topic. But you can create one global store per topic. Also, global stores don't need to be added to any processor and can be access by all processor automatically.

Our examples repo should help: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples

Also check out the docs: http://docs.confluent.io/current

Comment: Thank you. I have this use case where my state store is supposed to listen to more than one topic with different number of partitions and what i see is that my processor only works on messages coming from the common partitions only and messages that are in other partitions are not processed. I read i can achieve this by global state store which does not seem to be the solution anymore. Is there any other possible solution to make a state store to treat all partitions as same?

Comment: Maybe you can create a "proxy" topic and first read all data from your different topics and write it into this helper topic. Than use the helper topic to feed your store? The proxy topic would not need to have a log retention time and thus does not need to consumer a lot of storage in Kafka.

Comment: This is something that i can try. I think this will solve a lot of other things that i want to achieve. Thank You!

Comment: @Mathias J. Sax.. I tried to create a topic but for that should i create my own consumer or is there a way in stream to be able to create an intermediate topic. I will also need to control the way i produce msg to it so all the similar msg keys go to the same partition. I also want to be able to decide the number of partitions this topic can have. Thank You.

Comment: You can just create the topic with the number of partitions you need. Afterwards, you just copy the data via Kafka Streams: `builder.topic("t1").to("newTopic");` and `builder.topic("t2").to("newTopic");` and `builder.addGlobalStore(..."newTopic"...);`